# Does swallowing an exception remove the performance-hit of throwing it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, exception

After running into some un-handled exceptions when using `Response.Redirect()`, I read it up, and it appears several people are recommending to use `ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` instead, to avoid an unhandled `ThreadAbortException` for each redirect, and thereby avoiding a performance hit. But let's say you catch that exception instead like below...

```
try
{
    response.Redirect("Default.aspx", false);
    response.End();
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

Will this remove the hit on performance when the exception is now swallowed?

Comment: If in doubt, try profiling it. My suspicion is that catching the exception will have no performance improvement. Also, you can't really catch a ThreadAbortException, since it will automatically be rethrown at the end of the catch block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception is still being thrown, so all of the overhead of generating the exception and catching it is still present.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer throwing an exception costs about 0.042ms, plus about 0.026ms to do something with it. ***As long as the debugger is not attached.*** If I run it with the Visual Studio 2015 debugger this shoots up to about 15ms, the difference doing anything with it is lost in the noise.

Below is the test code and the results, but this is an arbitrary benchmark. I wouldn't use exceptions while parsing long lists of very bad data, I'd use TryParse().

If the overhead of exceptions is bad enough to be noticeable, first run it without the debugger, then you might want to re-write your code.

In non-debugging mode you can probably throw and handle thousands of exceptions every second, i.e. they are not expensive, use them plenty.

---

```
    private const int DataSize = 1000;
    private const string TestInt = "1";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
#if DEBUG
        Console.Write("DEBUG code, ");
#else
        Console.Write("RELEASE code, ");
#endif
        Console.Write(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ? "Debugger attached. " : "no debugger. ");
        Console.WriteLine($"{DataSize} of \"{TestInt}\"");

        var seedData = new List<string>();
        seedData.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(TestInt, DataSize));
        var stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        // Handled
        stopWatch.Restart();
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        foreach (var item in seedData)
        {
            try
            {
                var x = int.Parse(item);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        }
        var elapsed = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine($"Handled {elapsed}.");

        // Swallowed
        stopWatch.Restart();
        foreach (var item in seedData)
        {
            try
            {
                var x = int.Parse(item);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
        }
        elapsed = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine($"Swallowed {elapsed}.");

        // But I would do this task using TryParse()
        stopWatch.Restart();
        var failedStrings = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in seedData)
        {
            int x;
            if (!int.TryParse(item, out x))
                failedStrings.Add(item);
        }
        elapsed = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine($"Tryparse {elapsed}.");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

RELEASE code, no debugger. 1000 of "x"

> Handled 00:00:00.0632112.
>
> Swallowed 00:00:00.0366465.
>
> Tryparse 00:00:00.0000955.

DEBUG code, no debugger. 1000 of "x"

> Handled 00:00:00.0743439.
>
> Swallowed 00:00:00.0491802.
>
> Tryparse 00:00:00.0001026.

RELEASE code, Debugger attached. 1000 of "x"

> Handled 00:00:15.3732464.
>
> Swallowed 00:00:15.2940802.
>
> Tryparse 00:00:00.0001101.

DEBUG code, Debugger attached. 1000 of "x"

> Handled 00:00:15.1689722.
>
> Swallowed 00:00:15.1741098.
>
> Tryparse 00:00:00.0001026.

RELEASE code, no debugger. 1000 of "1"

> Handled 00:00:00.0001697.
>
> Swallowed 00:00:00.0001575.
>
> Tryparse 00:00:00.0001756.

DEBUG code, no debugger. 1000 of "1"

> Handled 00:00:00.0002214.
>
> Swallowed 00:00:00.0001946.
>
> Tryparse 00:00:00.0001093.

RELEASE code, Debugger attached. 1000 of "1"

> Handled 00:00:00.0001807.
>
> Swallowed 00:00:00.0003288.
>
> Tryparse 00:00:00.0003351.

DEBUG code, Debugger attached. 1000 of "1"

> Handled 00:00:00.0001117.
>
> Swallowed 00:00:00.0000884.
>
> Tryparse 00:00:00.0000911.